# Запрос на добавление данных из разных таблиц и одного элемента не из таблицы

Tags: postgresql, запрос, postgresql9.5

Есть таблица, в которую надо занести данные из 4-х таблиц и еще одно строковое значение.
Вот такой запрос пробовал:

```
INSERT INTO Position_Main(catCode, teachCode, posCode, kafCode, year) 
SELECT Category.catCode, Teach.teachCode, Position.posCode, Kafedra.kafCode 
FROM Category, Teach, Position, Kafedra 
WHERE Category.catName = 'sa' 
  AND Teach.teachName = 'assas' 
  AND Position.posName = 'Доцент' 
  AND Kafedra.kafName = 'ПОВТАС'
```

проблема в том, что к этому еще надо как-то year прикрутить. Для него таблицы нет, и хотелось бы решить эту задачу без ее создания. Объясните, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На крайний случай можно прибегнуть к такому варианту:

`SELECT <...>, 0 AS year FROM <...>`

Можно получать текущий год:

`SELECT <...>, date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE) FROM <...>`

Comment: Спасибо, но текущий год мне не нужен. Решил все же создать еще одну таблицу для годов. Теперь просто в WHERE добавляю еще одно условие